# Angular2 - assign pipe from a variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, pipe

Is it possible something like this:

```
{{property | some_variable_name}}
```

My goal is to use a `pipe` that is set in a `JSON` configuration (or a variable), but I'm not sure if it is possible to pass the `pipe` name in the interpolation this way.
Anybody tried something like this before?

Comment: is `some_variable_name` a predefined pipe or a custom one

Comment: Both ways. For example if I have `var pipeName = uppercase`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe needs to be listed in `pipes: [MyPipeHere]` in the `@Component()` decorator or in `PLATFORM_PIPES`, therefore this approach won't work.

What you can do instead is creating a custom pipe that calls other "pipes". A pipe is basically just a function, therefore this is easy.

You can pass a variable to your custom pipe like

```
{{property | my_custom_pipe:some_variable_name}}
```

this should be pretty close to what you want.

Comment: Yeah, my plan B was something like this, but I sill wasn't sure if it is possible. Thank you.