# Return a pipe through another pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe, angular-pipe

This is a follow-up question to [Angular2 - assign pipe from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940904/angular2-assign-pipe-from-a-variable/40505256#40505256)

What I'm looking for is a way to use a pipe based on a variable name.
I tried what Günter suggested and created a pipe that returns other pipes, but **how would you return another pipe and make sure it's not rendered as text?**

I have the following pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'piper'
})
export class PiperPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return `{{${value} | ${args}}}`;
  }
}
```

But when I feed it with a date string and "date" argument, like this:

```
<!-- with e.g. obj = { value: "2016-11-08T11:11:40.000Z", pipe: "date" } -->
<div>{{obj.value | obj.pipe}}</div>
```

It renders it as `innerText`:

```
<div>{{2016-11-08T11:11:40.000Z | date}}</div>
```

I tried `[innerHTML]` but no luck either.

Comment: try this piper:obj.value | piper:obj.date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create and call a pipe from the component in angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913541/how-to-create-and-call-a-pipe-from-the-component-in-angular-2)

Comment: You seem to be painting yourself into a corner with this use case. Why not use `[ngSwitch]` or similar and have different interpolation strings?